# Converting from list to matrix doesn't change the result of typeof function

Tags: r, list, matrix, typeof

Here's an example:

```
t <- list(a=1,b=2,c=3)
typeof(as.matrix(t))
```

If you run this in R (i'm using ubunutu R version 4.3.1), the typeof is still list. And if you make a matrix like matrix(c(1,2,3), ncol=3) the typeof would return matrix.
For another function, I require the type to be a matrix and it's throwing an error otherwise.

I'm not sure if this is a bug or an intended feature but I'd love if someone could explain what's going on.
I know I can solve this by calling unlist() and matrix() but I'd be interested to know why this is happening and if perhaps there's some easier way to solve this

Comment: from the documentation: 'as.matrix is a generic function. The method for data frames will return a character matrix if there is only atomic columns and any non-(numeric/logical/complex) column, applying as.vector to factors and format to other non-character columns. Otherwise, the usual coercion hierarchy (logical < integer < double < complex) will be used, e.g., all-logical data frames will be coerced to a logical matrix, mixed logical-integer will give a integer matrix, etc.'

Comment: Note that `typeof` is _never_ "matrix". `typeof` in R gives you the storage mode of the underlying data. If you do `typeof(matrix(0, 3, 3))` then you will get `"double"`.  In your case, you would need to do `typeof(as.matrix(unlist(t)))` to get the same result. If you want to test whether something is a `matrix`, you should use `inherits(as.matrix(t), 'matrix')`

Comment: there might be something in there which helps you. But also `class(as.matrix(t))` shows it is a matrix, while not a double

Comment: @Mark `inherits(object, 'matrix')` is the right way to find out if the `class` attribute contains `"matrix"`. For example, `inherits(t, 'matrix')` is FALSE but `inherits(as.matrix(t), 'matrix')` is TRUE

Comment: @AllanCameron I hope I never implied that it was! My comment was tangential to yours, and I hadn't seen it when I posted! Apologies for any confusion

Comment: https://youtu.be/V5M90oonAAg. This could be helpful for you

Comment: @AllanCameron Why not use `is.matrix`?

Comment: @KonradRudolph because I forgot it existed. I see it's a primitive function - I wonder why it needs to be. Presumably there are edge cases that other type checkers (some of which are also primitive) miss?

Comment: @AllanCameron “For compatibility with S”? Probably no real reason. — That doesn’t mean that it’s 100% consistent, though. S3 is broken anyway (`getS3method()` returns different results than what is being dispatched to in some cases) and nobody seems to care. :-(

Comment: @AllanCameron Actually [it checks whether the object has a `dim` attribute of length 2 and type `integer`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/75c5c84a193720d8d48f016ee57047f0e705ef43/src/include/Rinlinedfuns.h#L910). So `is.matrix(x)` will be `TRUE` even if its S3 class is *not* `matrix`. `is.matrix(structure(list(1), dim = c(1L, 1L)))` is `TRUE` (and R even prints it as if it was a matrix). You can even create heterogeneous matrices like this.

Comment: @KonradRudolph yes, but that object _is_ a matrix according to S3 (and it _kind of_ is a matrix in the broadest sense), so `inherits` and `class` think it's a matrix too. The difference comes if you have `structure(list(1), dim = c(1L, 1L), class = 'foo')` . Then `is.matrix` is TRUE but `inherits(x, 'matrix')` is FALSE.

Comment: @AllanCameron Ugh I **hate** the S3 implementation details. `unclass()` also doesn’t remove the class. — Anyway, it’s still not exactly the same since you can give the `matrix` class name to an object without making it a matrix, e.g. `structure(list(), class = 'matrix')` is *not* a matrix.

Comment: @KonradRudolph yeah, I guess `is.matrix` is better if you want to know whether an object is matrix-like, but even then you get `FALSE` with S4 objects like sparse matrices from {{Matrix}}. The best answer is probably `is.matrix` as long as the caveats are observed.

Answer (score 0):

as has been discussed in the commens as.matrix is using as.matrix.default method in both cases.

We can chase the differences down further but perhaps its  enough to recognise that the base::array function treats a named list input differently to a named vector input.

```
> str(array(list(a=1,b=2)))
List of 2
 $ : num 1
 $ : num 2
 - attr(*, "dim")= int 2

> str(array(c(a=1,b=2)))
 num [1:2(1d)] 1 2

as.matrix is a wrapper around the underlying array() call
```